# load wordpress tiny mce editor in plugin shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I want to integrate wordpress built in tiny MCE editor in my own plugin. I know that there is `wp_editor()` function that can be utilized for that purpose. Unfortunately, I want to load it in a shortcode that I made. And the way the shortcode works is by setting the expected output as the return value of the function. Thus, I need to find a way to concatenate the wordpress tiny MCE editor HTML string into the return value of my shortcode function.

```
public function submission_form(){
    $returnVal = "-- My own shortcode output --";
    $returnVal .= wp_tiny_mce_editor_please(); // <<== Does WP has this kind of function?
    $returnVal .= "-- End of my own shortcode output --";

    return $returnVal;
}
```

is there any function in wordpress that has similar functionality with `wp_editor()` but with returned html string instead of directly echo-ed inside the function?